# How to calculate the covariance between two stochastic integrals?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, covariance

How to calculate the covariance between the integral of a Brownian motion at different times:
$$\text{Cov}\left(\int^{t_1}_0\sigma(t)dW_t,\int^{t_2}_0\sigma(t)dW_t\right)\ ?$$
I know the answer is:
$$\int^{t_1\wedge t_2}_0\sigma^2(t)dt.$$

If $\int^{s}_0\sigma(t)dW_t$ was a Brownian motion, then the above answer would be obvious, but unfortunately it's not. So how to calculate such covariance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By:

1. bilinearity of covariance,
2. independence of Brownian increments, and
3. [Itô's isometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4_isometry),

we obtain:
$$\begin{align}
& \text{Cov}\left(\int^{t_1}_0\sigma(t)dW_t,\int^{t_2}_0\sigma(t)dW_t\right) 
\\[6pt] 
& \qquad = \text{Cov}\left(\int^{t_1\wedge t_2}_0\sigma(t)dW_t,\int^{t_1\wedge t_2}_0\sigma(t)dW_t +\int^{t_1\vee t_2}_{t_1\wedge t_2}\sigma(t)dW_t\right)
\\[6pt]
& \qquad \overset{1}{=} V\left(\int^{t_1\wedge t_2}_0\sigma(t)dW_t\right)+\text{Cov}\left(\int^{t_1\wedge t_2}_0\sigma(t)dW_t,\int^{t_1\vee t_2}_{t_1\wedge t_2}\sigma(t)dW_t\right)
\\[6pt]
& \qquad \overset{2}{=} E\left(\left(\int^{t_1\wedge t_2}_0\sigma(t)dW_t\right)^2\right)
\\[6pt]
& \qquad \overset{3}{=} \int^{t_1\wedge t_2}_0\sigma^2(t)dt
\end{align}$$

Comment: What do the notations $t_1\wedge t_2 $ and $t_1 \vee t_2 $ mean? How can we get the expectation in 2nd-last line?

Comment: $x\wedge y=\min(x,y)$, $x\vee y=\max(x,y)$. The expectation is obtained by noting that the covariance is null and using Itô’s Isometry.